# Download base64 image by opening save as popup

Tags: javascript, image

I have base64 image, which i want to download on the users machine.

I have tried below steps.

```
var url = base64Image.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]+/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
window.open(url);
```

and

```
window.location.href = base64Image.replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
```

By using these methods i am able to download the image by selecting the specific location. But i want user to provide the name for the file as well. Something like saveAs. Any hints please.

Also want to know if there is any way to handle ok/cancel buttons of save dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cant use JavaScript to do this. It's a browser feature to show dialogs.

Maybe, you want to provide name for your base64 image - then use library like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

Comment: If i use filesaver.js, then either i have to pass a hardcoded name or i have to display a prompt twice, once to get a name and second to get a location, which i dont think is feasible. So looking for a single popup solution.